# Is it possible to create a styled cell with pre-defined content?

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet

When you create a new styled notebook from the Stylesheets chooser dialag, you get a new notebook using the chosen style with some sample content provided.

[image]
[image]

---

But if you apply styles from the same stylesheet to an open blank notebook, there will be no sample content such as `Enter title here`

---

My question is how can I create one new cells with a given style and some sample content already present?

For example: I would like to be able to press `Alt+1` to create a Title-style cell with words `Enter title here`.

Comment: Why not just create a notebook with what you want. Whenever you want to use it, open that notebook and copy/paste. Or, if you want keyboard shortcuts, just use command-1 for titles, 2 for subtitles etc.

Comment: @bills Yes, I sometimes do that like what you said. But if the question is solvable, that'll be more convinient in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to go about this:

```
NotebookPut[Notebook[{Cell["Edit this", "Title"], 
    Cell["Edit that", "Subtitle"],
    Cell["type here", "Section"]}]];
```

This will create a new notebook with three cells: the first says "Edit this" in the "Title" style, the next says "Edit that" in the "Subtitle" style and the third says "type here" in the  "Section" style.